# How to get all unique values in a new column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have a pandas dataframe as shown below.

```
DF_Old =

id    tID       word   rA     rB
12    1         A      N      N
12    2         B      O      N
12    2         B      H      O
12    2         B      O      O
12    2         B      N      H
```

Every word in `word` with the same `tID` is the same word with different values in the columns `rA` and `rB`. I would like to create a new column `R` that includes all unique values in the columns `rA` and `rB` as shown below.

```
DF_New =

id    tID       word     R
12    1         A        N
12    2         B        O,N,H
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and each group flatten by [`numpy.ravel`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ravel.html), get unique values by [`/numpy.unique`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) and last if necessary `join`:

```
df = (df.groupby(['id','tID','word'])
       .apply(lambda x: ', '.join(np.unique(x.values.ravel())))
       .reset_index(name='R'))
print (df)
   id  tID word        R
0  12    1    A        N
1  12    2    B  H, N, O
```

Another solution with [`melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) and [`drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html), last only `join` values:

```
df = df.melt(['id','tID','word'], value_name='R').drop_duplicates(['id','tID','word', 'R'])
df = df.groupby(['id','tID','word'])['R'].apply(', '.join).reset_index()
print (df)
   id  tID word        R
0  12    1    A        N
1  12    2    B  O, H, N
```

Comment: Does this also work when the values in the columns aren't Strings?

Comment: @ThelMi - Yes, sure.

Comment: @ThelMi - only need before `join` cast to strings

Comment: .astype(str) I suppose?

Comment: @ThelMi - Yes, like `.apply(lambda x: ', '.join(np.unique(x.values.ravel()).astype(str)))`

Comment: @ThelMi - And for second solution `df['R'] = df['R'].astype(str)`

Comment: Sorry if I ask another question but what should I do if I have a lot of other columns in the df? I can't alter the names of all of them in your code.

Comment: @ThelMi Then need specify columns like `['rA','rB'].apply(lambda x: ', '.join(np.unique(x.values.ravel()).astype(str)))`